# Can someone convert this infix expression to prefix for me?

Tags: scheme

I can't quite wrap my head around converting from infix to prefix notation. This is the expression that I need to convert:

(8 * 7) + (2 + (3 * 4))

Here is my conversion:

write(+(* 8 7(+(* 3 4)2)))

This conversion equals 784 which is not the right answer.

If anyone could explain to me what I'm doing wrong I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: Check your parentheses - your first addition only has one operand while the first multiplication has three (`8`, `7`, and `(+ (* 3 4) 2)`). (In other words, you have `8 * 7 * (2 + 3 * 4)`.)

Answer (score 3):

Do it step by step: "operand operator operand" becomes "operator operand operand".

```
(8 * 7) ==> (* 8 7)
(3 * 4) ==> (* 3 4)
(* 8 7) + (2 + (* 3 4)) ==> (* 8 7) + (+ 2 (* 3 4))
(* 8 7) + (+ 2 (* 3 4)) ==> (+ (* 8 7) (+ 2 (* 3 4)))
```

Now, you can eliminate redundant operators and groups:

```
(+ (* 8 7) (+ 2 (* 3 4))) ==> (+ (* 8 7) 2 (* 3 4))
```

Answer (score 1):

should be (+(* 8 7)(+(2 (* 3 4)))), I think your problem is (* 8 7(...

you have to group (* 8 7).

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest:

```
write(+(* 8 7)(+(* 3 4)2))
```